# What's the role Qwidget and Qlayout in the QGIS interface?

Tags: qgis, pyqt, conda, interface

I use miniconda3 to manage my software installations, including QGIS, so I can use packages like geopandas easily in the QGIS python console. Lately however, when I open qgis from the command line like so:

```
$ conda activate ENV NAME
$ qgis
```

I get the following warnings in my terminal window:

```
Warning: QWidget::insertAction: Attempt to insert null action
Warning: QWidget::insertAction: Attempt to insert null action
Warning: QWidget::insertAction: Attempt to insert null action
Warning: QLayout: Attempting to add QLayout "" to QmsSearchResultItemWidget "", which already has a layout
```

My QGIS interface is obviously messed up when it opens. The tool bars have no dividing lines between them, the python console script editor window has this weird vertical line through the middle of the window, and sometimes the 'Select Color' window pops up behind my symbology window. I believe this is tied to the Qwidget and Qlayout warnings above, but I just dont know enough about the specifics of the Qt library to fully diagnose the problem for myself.

What I have tried:

I have tried removing the env where I have qgis installed completely and updating my base conda.
I have removed and reinstalled qgis several different times with different versions. The problem exists with 3.10 (LTR) 3.12 and 3.14.

My Set up:

I am running QGIS on a Mac (osx 10.15.5 Catalina).
I install QGIS in a specific conda env for easy access to Python modules in the QGIS console, and qgis functions in my stand-alone scripts. (conda version: 4.8.3)

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I am having exactly the same issue. Catalina 10.15.7, QGIS installed in virtual environment, conda 4.8.5, QGIS 3.14.16-Pi